# Access to modified closure, is this a ReSharper bug?

Tags: c#, lambda, resharper, closures

I have the latest ReSharper 5.0 build (1655), where I have encountered the suggestion 'Access to modified closure' on the following code:

```
var now = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
dates.Where(d => d > now);
...
now = new DateTime();
```

and the `now` inside the lambda expression is underlined with the warning.

I'm pretty sure that's a ReSharper bug, but is it really?

**EDIT:** I should have checked better, there was an assignment to `now` later in the code.

**EDIT 2** Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591677/access-to-modified-closure-is-this-a-resharper-bug/2591754#2591754) below pretty much answers this, but what about the following:

```
var query = dates.Where(d => d > now).ToList();
```

Shouldn't this solve the problem by executing the query immediately?

Comment: Literally just on that code? No assignment to "now" after those lines?

Comment: @Jon Skeet You're right, there was an assignment a few lines down! I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, now you've modified the question, it makes complete sense. You're modifying a variable used within a closure - which can produce unexpected results:

```
var now = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
var query = dates.Where(d => d > now);
...
now = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1);
foreach (DateTime date in query)
{
    // This will only see dates after 1990, not after 1970
    // This would confuse many developers.
}
```

In fact, it's not just a matter of when the query starts - you could modify it *while iterating over the results*:

```
var now = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
var query = dates.Where(d => d > now);
...
foreach (DateTime date in query)
{
    now = date;
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

That will give a strictly-increasing sequence of dates... again, somewhat confusing.

R# is absolutely right to warn about this, IMO. It can *sometimes* be useful - but should be used with great care.

Comment: What if I call `ToList()`, shouldn't this execute the query immediately, thus preventing this situation?

Comment: @hmemcpy: The warning remains because R# doesn't know that the closure is never used again. Is it mean to know about every method which might use a closure? R# doesn't know that `ToList()` will execute the query immediately and then throw away the source.

Answer (score 1):

What ReSharper is warning you about is that the value of `now` is being captured in the lambda expression and is not the value you think it is when the lambda gets executed.

To solve your problem, you need to assign the value of `now` to a local variable before you use it:

```
var now = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var dates = new List<DateTime>{new DateTime(2001, 12, 12)};
DateTime localNow = now;
dates.Where(d => d > localNow);

now = new DateTime(2003, 12, 12);
```

If you want to read more, the ReSharper forum has a [post](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/273042) on it which includes several links with further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No this is resharper thinking you are modifying the contents of a collection while looping over it, `dates` most probably. You can safely ignore this.

Comment: Since `now` is a captured variable any changes to it before query is evaluated will most likely yield a different result than expected, which is what R# is trying to highlight.

Comment: hmm apparently the question was changed to code where he does use a loop